# How to serialize Java class into XML with specified Schema

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, smooks

I have a Joo.java class and I want to serialize it into XML using the schema
JooSchema.xsd.

Is it possible with Smooks API, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is better achieved with JAXB.